# Blank screen with AIR 3.7 on iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an AIR for iOS app. I built it with Flash Professional CS6 and FlashDevelop. The app is already available in the AppStore.

I wanted to submit an update when I got the notice to support iPhone 5 resolution.

I then added the Default-568h@2x.png and it works perfrectly on iPhone 4 & 5 with AIR SDK 3.4.

When I try to submit, the app gets rejected with the following comment:
"Invalid Launch Image - Your app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later."

I guess that's because I built the app with AIR SDK 3.4, but when I update the SDK and build with 3.5, 3.6 or 3.7 I get the following behaviour:
Everything works fine when testing in Flash Professional CS6
When I copy the .IPA to my device the start screen shows up correctly but then a blank screen (with the background color of the stage) appears and nothing happens.

Does anyone know what's happening?

Thanks for looking into this!
Hannes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution to my problem. I was loading external .swf files without loading them into the same ApplicationDomain. I added the following code and now it's working:

```
var _lc:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, null);
_loader.load(_urlRequest, _lc);
```